# Changing x-axis labels to hours instead of the sample number

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I currently have a dataset of 70,000 samples (sampled at 1Hz), and I am graphing it using MatPlotLib.

I am wondering how to change the x-axis labels to be in hours, instead of sample #.

The code that I am using today is as follows:

```
test = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep='\t')
test.columns = ['TS', 'ppb', 'ppm']
test.head()

# The first couple minutes were with an empty container
# Then the apple was inserted into the container.
fig5 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig5.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(test.index, test['ppm'])
ax1.set_ylabel('(ppm)', color='b')
ax1.set_xlabel('Sampling Time', color='k')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.scatter(test.index, test['ppb'], color = 'c')
ax2.set_ylabel('(ppb)', color='c')

plt.show
```

My data looks as follows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If ``TS`` contains the times, why not do ``ax1.scatter(test['TS'], test['ppm'])``?

Comment: If its at 1Hz, then every 3600 samples would be one hour. So create a new column that's something like `test['hours'] = (test.index - test.index[0])/3600.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is sampled at 1Hz, that means that every 3600 samples is one hour. So create a new column like:

```
test['hours'] = (test.index - test.index[0])/3600.0
```